# Is $\log |z - w \overline{z}|$ plurisubharmonic?

Tags: complex-analysis

Consider the real valued function 
$$
  \phi(z,w) = \log |z - w \overline{z}|
$$
defined on the open set $G = \{(z,w) \in \mathbb{C}^2: |z| < 2, |w| < 1\}$. I want to show that the function $\phi$ is plurisubharmonic on $G$. Recall that plurisubharmonic means the restriction to each complex line intersect the domain is a subharmonic function. Or alternatively, since the given function is smooth on $G$ the complex Hessian matrix is positive semi-definite on $G$.

Is $\phi$ plurisubharmonic on $G$? If not, is it at least plurisubharmonic on the set
$$ G_1 := \{(z + w, zw): |z|, |w| < 1\}?$$

Comment: why do you think $\phi$ is smooth?

Comment: @zhw The function $\phi$ is smooth because the expression inside the modulus is never zero on the domain.

Comment: What aout $(z,w)=(0,0)?$

Comment: @zhw you are right. I was a bit hasty. But since we are taking a log, it suffices to prove that it is psh at those points where $\phi$ is not $-\infty$.